# I am installing tensorflow my laptop graphic is Intel HD Graphics 520(Skylake GT2)

Tags: tensorflow

my laptop graphic  is Intel HD Graphics 520(Skylake GT2) and I want to install tensorflow. there is intalled anaconda program already. actually I installed tensorflow,but when I run program with using pyvcharm, there represent future warning and program runs too slow. 
so I want to know that either I can install tensorflow-gpu and how.
If that is not impossible how can I install tensorflow without any warning.

Comment: Please go through [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is the question standard followed by most of the SO posts. Please add examples? Show us the errros? point us to the exact problem?

Comment: tensorflow-gpu only works on nvidia GPUs by default